# Lock specific dict entry (> Python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, locking

I have a nested dict data structure that looks like this:

```
{
"key1": {
"key1_level1": [],
"key1_level2": [],
}
}
```

I have multiple threads reading and writing on each of these individual lists (either in key1 or key2). I am only looking to lock the specific list that the thread is locking on, not lock the entire dict, every time we have a thread acting on this data structure.

What would be the best way to achieve this in python?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the list immutable (not editable) when you say "lock" you can use the frozenlist package https://pypi.org/project/frozenlist/ to make it immutable when you edit it

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately, the list cannot be made immutable in this scenario. We frequently append and remove elements from each of these dicts.